# ios scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval for amount of time

Tags: ios, nstimer

I want to use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to do a periodic task for certain amount of time lets say one hour. but How do I implement on my code. Here is my code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                          target: self
                                        selector: @selector(doSomething:)
                                        userInfo: nil
                                         repeats: YES];
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Breakpoint the `doSomething:` method and see if it's being called.

Answer (score 6):

Lets assume for a minute .

Here is simple scenario ,

```
int remainingCounts;
NSTimer *timer;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:(self) selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
remainingCounts = 60;   // int remainingCounts ;...
```

Method being called for every sec.

```
-(void)countDown {
    NSLog(@"%d", remainingCounts);
    // Do Your stuff......
    if (--remainingCounts == 0) {
        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```