# Creating control pad

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to code a controller for an image view to move using buttons.

inside up button code :

```
-(IBAction)upButton:(id)sender{
    mainChac.center = CGPointMake(mainChac.center.x, mainChac.center.y - 5);   
}
```

code is working properly but I have to tap it repeatedly to keep moving up, I wanna know which method to call, to move it, while holding the up button.

edit :

```
-(void)touchDownRepeat{

        mainChac.center = CGPointMake(mainChac.center.x, mainChac.center.y - 5);

}

-(IBAction)upButton:(id)sender{

    [upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownRepeat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];

}
```

edit 2: solution

```
-(void)moveUp{
    mainChac.center = CGPointMake(mainChac.center.x, mainChac.center.y - 5);

}

- (void)holdDown
{
    NSLog(@"hold Down");

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)holdRelease
{
    NSLog(@"hold release");
    [timer invalidate];

}

-(IBAction)upButton:(id)sender{

    [upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Comment: did you attach the button with `touchUpInside` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

What you need to to have 2 events, one for while the button is pressed down and another for when the button is released like so:

```
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(holdRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


 - (void)holdDown
  {
     NSLog(@"hold Down");
  }

  - (void)holdRelease
  {
      NSLog(@"hold release");

  }
```

Have your hold down function start a loop, and your holdRelease stop the loop.

**EDIT-2:**

An easy way (but perhaps not the best way) to achieve this loop would be to use `NSTImer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` inside the hold down and invalidate it in the release method.

all of this stuff has been done before, please try googling this stuff. Here is a stackoverlfow question with an example: [ios scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval for amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225164/ios-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-for-amount-of-time)

Comment: I already saw that link, I can't figure out on how to move an image while holding upButton.

Comment: @frustratediOSdeveloper `touchDownRepeat` is called multiple times, set it to that, and as you hold down your finger it will keep calling and run the code

Comment: @frustratediOSdeveloper please edit your question and add the code there, thats very difficult to read

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work. what's happening is that I have to tap the button multiple times to move the image. I edited the code :)

Comment: @frustratediOSdeveloper `touchDownRepeat` is not a delegate! when you created `upButton` inside InterfaceBuilder you assigned it to the **event** `touchUpInside`. Delete the connection, create a new connection and when the popup shows, don't select `touchUpInside` select `touchDownRepeat `

Comment: touch down repeat works if I tap on the button twice quickly then the code inside the scope will work, but if I just tap the button and hold it, nothing will happen.

Comment: I am really sorry but I can't figure the loop out. can you provide an example.

Comment: thanks! NSTimer did it, I suppose it's not the best way, but it works now! thanks again!

Comment: @frustratediOSdeveloper no prob, happy coding